# Extract words from environment variable into two strings

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, with two variables like this

```
OS = foo.o bar.o baz.o
WS = -DWITH_FOO -DWITH_BAR -DWITH_BAZ
```

And so on. Instead of writing this out manually I want to generate these two when the makefile is executed based on an environment variable called `WITH` containing something like `foo bar baz`. If this environment variable is not set, or is empty, the makefile should use some hard-coded fallback instead.

How would I do that? I'm not too good at makefiles, all I can think is some kind of 'foreach` call but the specifics elude me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would write something like this:

```
ifdef WITH
  OS := $(WITH:%=%.o)
  WS := $(WITH:%=-DWITH_%)
else
  # Fallback.
endif
```

This is the most straightforward solution I see, however, it is not 100% good because `WS` would be `-DWITH_foo ...` instead of `-DWITH_FOO ...`.

If such behavior does not fit your needs, you can use `tr` command to convert `WS` to uppercase:

```
WS := $(shell echo '$(WS)' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
```

Or, as more portable option, use `tr` function from [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/):

```
WS := $(call tr,$([a-z]),$([A-Z]),$(WS))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. I may look into GMSL at some point, but for now it's fine this way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using GNU Make on a UNIX-like operating system, here is a possible solution:

```
afineman@hotdog:/tmp$ cat Makefile
WITH = foo bar baz
WITH_UPPER = $(shell echo $(WITH) | tr a-z A-Z)

OS = $(WITH:%=%.o)
WS = $(WITH_UPPER:%=-DWITH_%)

.PHONY: env
env:
    @echo WITH=$(WITH)
    @echo WITH_UPPER=$(WITH_UPPER)
    @echo OS=$(OS)
    @echo WS=$(WS)
afineman@hotdog:/tmp$ make
WITH=foo bar baz
WITH_UPPER=FOO BAR BAZ
OS=foo.o bar.o baz.o
WS=-DWITH_FOO -DWITH_BAR -DWITH_BAZ
afineman@hotdog:/tmp$
```

You can supply `WITH` in your environment if you wish, but in general it is better to write your Makefiles so that they are self-contained.  If you do have a requirement that WITH comes from the environment, just leave out the first line of the above Makefile, and `$(WITH)` will come from the environment.

You can also override `$WITH` by running Make with the `-e` switch, i.e.,

```
afineman@hotdog:/tmp$ WITH="bing bang buzz" make   # Not overridden
WITH=foo bar baz
WITH_UPPER=FOO BAR BAZ
OS=foo.o bar.o baz.o
WS=-DWITH_FOO -DWITH_BAR -DWITH_BAZ
afineman@hotdog:/tmp$ WITH="bing bang buzz" make -e   # Overridden
WITH=bing bang buzz
WITH_UPPER=BING BANG BUZZ
OS=bing.o bang.o buzz.o
WS=-DWITH_BING -DWITH_BANG -DWITH_BUZZ
```

Comment: Thank you. I want the standard procedure to be self-contained, the WITH is only if someone wants to change which parts are compiled